# Is there any pattern like pagefactory in robotium?

Tags: android, robotium

I m trying to build an automation test case environment for our Android application by using robotium. Although robotium could run right now, I'm still confused about how to make the test case more brief or organized. Now the test case seems very complicated and chaotic.
When I use selenium, there's a pagefactory pattern.

Is there anything like that in robotium?

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to differentiate between the two patterns, ***Page Object*** and ***Page Factory***.

- The ***Page Object*** pattern is implemented by making classes that represent web pages (or the equivilent in a moble app).
- The ***Page Factory*** pattern is a combination of the ***Page Object*** and ***[Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)*** patterns.  Selenium does come with classes to implement a *PageObject Factory* pattern, but implementation can be tricky and bug-prone, and my coworkers and I have not found it desirable to use.

So, since the ***Page Object*** pattern is what you really want, I'll show you some of what my coworkers and I have come up with to implement this pattern in Robotium.

In Robotium, the rough equivilent of the Selenium WebDriver is the Solo class.  It's basically a [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for a bunch of other objects at once (you can see a list of all the involved classes in the [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/jayway/robotium/tree/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo)).

To implement a Page Object pattern with the Robotium Solo object, first start with an abstract Page Object with a Solo field (like in Selenium where you would have a WebDriver field).

```
public abstract class AppPage {

    private Solo solo;

    public AppPage(Solo solo) {
        this.solo = solo;
    }

    public Solo getSolo() {
        return this.solo;
    }   
}
```

Then, extend AppPage for each page, like so:

```
public class MainPage extends AppPage {

    public MainPage(Solo solo) {
        super(solo);
    }

    // It is useful to be able to chain methods together.

    // For public methods that direct you to other pages,
    // return the Page Object for that page.
    public OptionsPage options() {
        getSolo().clickOnButton(getSolo().getString(R.string.options_button));
        return new OptionsPage(getSolo());
    }

    //For public methods that DON'T direct you to other pages, return this.
    public MainPage searchEntries(String searchWord) {
        EditText search = (EditText) solo.getView(R.id.search_field);
        solo.enterText(search, searchWord);
        return this;
    }
}
```

There are a lot more fancy things you can do when implementing a Page Object pattern in Robotium, but this will get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [Robotium-Sandwich](https://github.com/pwojnaro/robotium-sandwich) project. Robotium-Sandwich makes it super easy to create page objects for Robotium.

Answer (score -1):

You can Use the Page Objects as in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Comment: Hi! Please remember always to describe with text or with code your answers. Just a link to external site is not a good alternative.